# MySQL: Group By multiple columns not giving exact results

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

I have a table that contains 5 columns namely:

> before_1, before_2, before_3, rule, name

where before_1,before_2, and before_3 are the three words before the name/word in a document.

What I wanted to find was:

> Which are the two words that occur together before a name. I don't want just the top words, but all the words sorted by the number of occurrences.

I tried the following few queries but that didn't work for me.

```
select count(before_2),count(before_3),name from data_with_before_words group by name;
```

I got the same count for both columns, which is not what I was expecting.

Example data:

First 5 rows:

```
before_1,before_2,before_2,rule,name

a,league,of,Persona,Amell
the,assasin,of,Persona,Amell
the,league,of,Persona,Amell
a,assasin,of,Persona,Amell
a,league,of,Persona,Amell
```

Expected Output:

```
league,of,3,Amell
assasin,of,2,Amell
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its better to include sample and expected data relevant to your question

Comment: Please add input data and expected output you want

Comment: I have added the example.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the expected output you can use following query

```
select before_2,before_3,name,count(*)
from data_with_before_words 
group by before_2,before_3,name
order by count(*) desc
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/HMO46747)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Query:

```
select count(res1.comWords) as occurrences, res1.name from (select concat(before_1,"-", before_2) as comWords, name from data_with_before_words) res1 group by res1.name order by occurrences desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
SELECT before_2,before_3,name FROM data_with_before_words GROUP BY before_2,before_3,name Having count(*)>=1
```